# I got TradingView's 'end of line without continuation' error with Pine Script, please

Tags: pine-script

I got TradingView's 'end of line without continuation' error with Pine Script for this line:

[image]

How to fix that error with this function code? anybody can help me?

Comment: Please don't post your code as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to have multi line statements, your next line should begin with one or several (**different from multiple of 4**) spaces. [Source](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Line_wrapping.html)

From what I can see from your screenshot, your lines start with multiples of 4 spaces on line 24 and 25. And this is why you shouldn't post your code as a screenshot.